# codename one nfc beacon

Tags: nfc, codenameone, beacon

i am trying to do some tests with nfc and beacons with Codename One. I'm reading that Codename One doesn't support them on some old posts, any news about it? It seems that the only way is going on native but i'm totally new to it. Any suggestions where to start or any hint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the source code for a couple of CN1Libs at http://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html

There you can see some of the native code implementations. It is more challenging to write a native interface, since the autocomplete won't generally work and the simulator can't test it. If you can find code examples similar to what you want to achieve written for Andriod, iOS, etc., on GitHub or other places, that can give you a head start.

Also, you can download the source code of your build and load it into Android Studio or XCode and debug it there.

Comment: Great answer, I'd also add a couple of helpful references to the developer guide: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_native_interfaces and how do I video https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: Thank you James, i noticed that autocompletation didn't work on native android and also the NetBeans highlights errors for everything but the build works fine once you send it on the web server.

Thank you Shai for the guide i haven't noticed that guide and it was VERY helpful and complete. I managed to do a simple app to check if the NFC is on or off and AndroidNativeUtil was the thing i was searching for.

Comment: Ok, now i got other problems. All the Android examples i find on NFC are about modifying the mainActivity methods(like onNewIntent). In fact, i need that, because when i put my NFC card near the phone it should fire an event and catch it. How can i accomplish that? In the android native code i just have my interface class.

Comment: Add another CN1 class with static variables and methods that you can have your native class call instead of having the native class try to interact with Activities and such. The static class can then update the view or call something in StateMachine, etc. Just make sure you use CallSerially when you want to update the view as the native classes run on a different thread.

Comment: Mmm...i am not sure of what are you saying. In the examples about NFC in Android they are always using the main activity, working with onNewIntent, and catpuring the data of the NFC tag inside the intent. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this interaction back then. Here is an example of adding a broadcast receiver which is similar https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-intercept-incoming-sms-on-android.html if you can point me at a specific API you are having trouble integrating I can provide a more accurate analysis