# Codename one NFC Integration

Tags: nfc, codenameone

There's a way from Codename One to provide access to Near Field Communication (NFC) ?
Anything new, out this post [codename-one-nfc-beacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279837/codename-one-nfc-beacon)?

Answer (score 1):

NFC is an Android only API and even there the availability in devices is "problematic". In iOS it's restricted to payment so there is no access to the underlying hardware. So there is no point in supporting the API in a framework that is designed for cross platform. I'm sure you can create a cn1lib similar to the fingerprint reader API or the [SMS intercept API](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-intercept-incoming-sms-on-android.html).

Comment: Flutter NFC plug-in works on both Android and iOS...

Comment: This was a response from 2017 when this was indeed true. Apple has since enabled NFC for developers. We can probably release a library for it as well if there's demand.